# Twistcli podman in pipeline

Tags: gitlab, containers, gitlab-ci, podman

I keep getting this error when I try to use **twistcli** to scan a container using *podman*:

`failed to augment data: Error: error mounting storage for container c494c177d35d905aa267f0eebccf67dce2bcd0b61bc1511ef7039fde07baf152: error creating aufs mount to /var/lib/containers/storage/aufs/mnt/b5da5a775dc2fcd81fb1ca5b658415cb5e94450ed1cf0861dc4214a3d3fe9285: invalid argument`

In the current configuration I'm trying to run *twistcli* in the *gitlab ci* pipeline, using Ubuntu 21.04 as an image on which podman is then installed on top.

Pipeline .gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
  - scan

scan:
  stage: scan
  image: ubuntu:21.04
  script:

    - apt-get update
    - apt-get -y install curl
    #- apt install software-properties-common uidmap
    #- add-apt-repository ppa:projectatomic/ppa
    - apt-get -y upgrade
    - apt-get -y install podman 
  
    - podman info
    - podman login docker.io -u sim55649 -p $DOCKER_PASS
    - podman pull docker.io/alpine:latest
    #- cat ~/etc/containers/storage.conf

    - curl -k -u $PRISMA_USER:$PRISMA_PASS --output ./twistcli $PRISMA_ADD/api/v1/util/twistcli
    - more ./twistcli
    - chmod a+x ./twistcli
    - df /var/lib/containers/.
    - ./twistcli images scan --address $PRISMA_ADD --user $PRISMA_USER --password $PRISMA_PASS --details alpine:latest
```

How can this error be solved?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How does your pipeline look like?

Comment: were you able to solve that? i have a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72316730/prisma-cloud-twistcli-with-podman-error-destination-must-be-a-directory-when