# prisma cloud - twistcli with podman error - destination must be a directory when copying from stdin

Tags: jenkins, prisma, podman

i try the first time to use twistcli to scan my images. I have installed podman and twistcli in a separate container(at_ubi8_minimal_adp_jenkins_slave) from where i execute the commands:

```
podman login
podman pull
twistcli images scan
```

from the command twistcli images scan i receive this error message:

```
failed to augment data: time="2022-05-20T08:22:27Z" level=error msg="Unmounting /home/jenkins/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay/acaf4e2debbf7544bed43772631cff07a849b5efe16af0e80495410e75fa7434/merged: invalid argument"
Error: destination must be a directory when copying from stdin
```

here the detailed output from the jenkins job:

```
Running on twistcli-500j7-lj54g in /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/prod-images/at_ubi8_minimal_openjdk17_tomcat_9
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ
[Pipeline] sh
+ twistcli --version
twistcli version 22.01.882
+ podman login --username ***** --password **** ******.azurecr.io
time="2022-05-20T08:19:55Z" level=warning msg="\"/\" is not a shared mount, this could cause issues or missing mounts with rootless containers"
Login Succeeded!
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] withCredentials
Masking supported pattern matches of $PASSWORD
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ podman pull ****.azurecr.io/base-images-untested/at_ubi8_minimal_openjdk17_tomcat_9:latest
Trying to pull *****.azurecr.io/base-images-untested/at_ubi8_minimal_openjdk17_tomcat_9:latest...
Getting image source signatures
Copying blob sha256:f90c6277a08b98bf86bd25eb57a1eb468537eb32981d7505fe0899b9fe4fdbf9
Copying blob sha256:0344366a246a0f7590c2bae4536c01f15f20c6d802b4654ce96ac81047bc23f3
Copying blob sha256:a65df433bed4dabe5b1e2674bf8445f146c74692883416bd13cb2d3220eff12e
Copying blob sha256:2fba5451984251ebb2e5fa24790dafa11fed899762e072f0e2850c735eb72c9b
Copying blob sha256:4752687a61a97d6f352ae62c381c87564bcb2f5b6523a05510ca1fb60d640216
Copying blob sha256:f05c02598dd61f434ad35163b5ba33a78088edd6663230692bc9a86b32f17f08
Copying blob sha256:0344366a246a0f7590c2bae4536c01f15f20c6d802b4654ce96ac81047bc23f3
Copying blob sha256:727d2b3b1e88b86022ad6ad83883eb33125ddf60c5be90b4a60a6e4c17d47747
Copying blob sha256:f90c6277a08b98bf86bd25eb57a1eb468537eb32981d7505fe0899b9fe4fdbf9
Copying blob sha256:f05c02598dd61f434ad35163b5ba33a78088edd6663230692bc9a86b32f17f08
Copying blob sha256:085c9b1c02e10303ae1b89674babfaa65e200ef6a8f7efd54d53b5a09457ff2c
Copying blob sha256:d384ab88b54fb8d6d94389d243defb197150a922d9544df3b7a99b3dba2322fc
Copying blob sha256:2fba5451984251ebb2e5fa24790dafa11fed899762e072f0e2850c735eb72c9b
Copying blob sha256:4752687a61a97d6f352ae62c381c87564bcb2f5b6523a05510ca1fb60d640216
Copying blob sha256:a65df433bed4dabe5b1e2674bf8445f146c74692883416bd13cb2d3220eff12e
Copying blob sha256:727d2b3b1e88b86022ad6ad83883eb33125ddf60c5be90b4a60a6e4c17d47747
Copying blob sha256:d384ab88b54fb8d6d94389d243defb197150a922d9544df3b7a99b3dba2322fc
Copying blob sha256:ccc5a3e54104978dbefc422db00d01071aa635c0213b5e7634ab248804578fe8
Copying blob sha256:5d0a4158bbb9c76f1ad9c2164e11d6dd19286e9e28366340aaa068bc36731343
Copying blob sha256:085c9b1c02e10303ae1b89674babfaa65e200ef6a8f7efd54d53b5a09457ff2c
Copying blob sha256:f05bd034f93deb8750b9bfab26ccf6cd6867f145250640216d9996cd7078a1ed
Copying blob sha256:ccc5a3e54104978dbefc422db00d01071aa635c0213b5e7634ab248804578fe8
Copying blob sha256:4f4fb700ef54461cfa02571ae0db9a0dc1e0cdb5577484a6d75e68dc38e8acc1
Copying blob sha256:5d0a4158bbb9c76f1ad9c2164e11d6dd19286e9e28366340aaa068bc36731343
Copying blob sha256:f05bd034f93deb8750b9bfab26ccf6cd6867f145250640216d9996cd7078a1ed
Copying blob sha256:4f4fb700ef54461cfa02571ae0db9a0dc1e0cdb5577484a6d75e68dc38e8acc1
Copying config sha256:54900d37234bebdbaf6223504b2d63a5fbeb3906ab1513cac9587cff75d9d297
Writing manifest to image destination
Storing signatures
54900d37234bebdbaf6223504b2d63a5fbeb3906ab1513cac9587cff75d9d297
+ unset http_proxy
+ unset https_proxy
+ unset no_proxy
+ twistcli images scan --details --podman-path podman --address https://***prisma-console*** -u ***** -p **** ****.azurecr.io/base-images-untested/at_ubi8_minimal_openjdk17_tomcat_9:latest
failed to augment data: time="2022-05-20T08:22:27Z" level=error msg="Unmounting /home/jenkins/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay/acaf4e2debbf7544bed43772631cff07a849b5efe16af0e80495410e75fa7434/merged: invalid argument"
Error: destination must be a directory when copying from stdin
```

does anyone know what this error message means?

Answer (score 0):

There are many questions that would be necessary to understand your implementation, but from my experience the issue is with "/home/jenkins/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay/acaf4e2debbf7544bed43772631cff07a849b5efe16af0e80495410e75fa7434/merged". Does this directory already exist on your container? If not, it would need to be created before it can be a destination path. At a glance, this looks like a temp dir, maybe? That would not work, especially, a rootless scenario. When I see "failed to augment data" my first thoughts are the directory does not exist or I do not have the necessary access for said directory. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue, you have to just pass one parameter
--containerized